# contraints on parameters in MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, constraint

I run a basic version of mcmc, based on example given in this [Metropolis-Hasting tutorial](https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/MH_intro.html)

```
x = rep(0,10000)
x[1] = 3     #initialize; I've set arbitrarily set this to 3
for(i in 2:10000){
  current_x = x[i-1]
  proposed_x = current_x + rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=1)
  A = target(proposed_x)/target(current_x) 
  if(runif(1)<A){
    x[i] = proposed_x       # accept move with probabily min(1,A)
  } else {
    x[i] = current_x        # otherwise "reject" move, and stay where we are
  }
}
```

but get often negative values for parameters which should be strictly positive (it's a physiological model with parameters such as growth, transfer etc.). I use uniform priors because I don't know anything about these intracellular parameters.

What is the best way to constraint the MCMC? I heard of simple techniques like taking the absolute value if a negative one is proposed but for sure there other methods as well. 
Any comments would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

After remarks from Taylor I expanded my code, see below the more complete version of the mcmc algorithm for multiple parameters. As explained before, I ran an ODE model to get the predictions, based on which I calculate the log-likelihood. Setting the model prediction to 0 solved the issue with negative values!

```
#######################################################################
# mcmc - main function for N parameters
# INPUTS:
# iterNum   - iteration number
# startVal  - initial guess
# propSD    - st dev for kernel - FIXED for now
# expTimes  - experimental data times
# expData   - experimental data 
# priorL/U  - lower, upper bound for the uniform prior 
# sigma     - st.dev for observation error - FIXED
# optVar    - optimized variable 
#######################################################################

mcmc <- function(iterNum,startVal,propSD,priorL,priorU,
                         expTimes,expData,sigma,optVar) {

  n <- length(expTimes)
  parNumber <- length(startVal)

  alpha <- array(0,dim=c(iterNum,parNumber))
  alphaProp <- rep(0,parNumber)

  alpha[1,] <- startVal;  # X1,...,Xn initial values
  alphaCurr <- startVal;  # initializing current parameter array
  alphaProp <- alphaCurr;

  for (i in 2:iterNum) {

    for (j in 1:parNumber) {

      alphaCurr[j] = alpha[i-1,j]
      modelPred <- getModelPred(alphaCurr,expTimes,optVar)
      alphaProp[j] <- rnorm(1,mean = alphaCurr[j],sd = propSD)

      # checks value of the new proposal - it gives zero probability for parameter values outside of desired range
      if (alphaProp[j]>0) {
        modelPredProp <- getModelPred(alphaProp,expTimes,optVar)
      } else { 
        modelPredProp <- 0
      } 

      # logPriors & logLikes {
      logPriorProp <- logPriorUnif(priorL,priorU)
      logPrior <- logPriorUnif(priorL,priorU)
      logLikeProp <- logLikeNormal(modelPredProp,expData,sigma)
      logLike <- logLikeNormal(modelPred,expData,sigma)

      # ImportanceRatio 
      IR <- getIR(logPriorProp,logPrior,logLikeProp,logLike)

      A = min(1, IR)
      if (runif(1) < A) {
        alpha[i,] = alphaProp
      }
      else
        alpha[i,] = alphaCurr
      end
    }
  }
  return(alpha)
}

#######################################################################
# logLikeNormal - Normal Log-Likelihood for following arguments:
# x - n experimental data points  --> n - number of exp points
# f - n model predictions
# sigma - st.dev for observation error - FIXED
#######################################################################
logLikeNormal <- function(x,f,sigma) {
  n <- length(x)
  pointLL= array(0,dim=c(1,n))
  for (i in 1:n) {
    pointLL[i] = -n/2*log(sigma^2) - 1/2*sum((x[i]-f[i])^2/sigma^2) 
  }
  return(sum(pointLL))
}
```

Comment: Use an appropriate model!  If the parameters must be positive and you model them with a Normal distribution that assigns substantial probability to negative values, then *a fortiori* the model is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest fix would be to change your `target` function so that it gives zero probability for parameters that are outside of the desired range. This can be caused by one or both of these two things:

1. Put zero prior probability on values outside of the desired range, and/or
2. Choose a likelihood that doesn't take values outside of the range.

In this case, if you propose parameters outside of the desire range, your acceptance probability will evaluate to $0$.

Alternatively, you might transform your parameters, and sample on the transformed space. When I do this, I tend to use a random walk proposal, just like you are, but I change the target by taking into account Jacobians.